# Is it possible to show that $\operatorname{Arg}z$ is not an analytic function by using the Cauchy–Riemann differential equations?

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to show that $\operatorname{Arg}z$ is not an analytic function by using the Cauchy–Riemann differential equations.

After a quick search I've found this:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_%28mathematics%29): Alternatively, the principal value can be calculated in a uniform way using the tangent half-angle formula, the function being defined over the complex plane but excluding the origin:

$
\operatorname{Arg}(x + iy) = 
\begin{cases}
2 \arctan \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x} \right) & \qquad x > 0 \text{ or } y \ne 0  \\
\pi & \qquad x < 0 \text{ and } y = 0 \\
\text{undefined} & \qquad  x = 0 \text{ and } y = 0
\end{cases}
$

Unfortunately, I was not able to make further progress. My question: Is it possible to show that $\operatorname{Arg}z$ is not an analytic function by using the Cauchy–Riemann differential equations?

Comment: $\operatorname{Arg}:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ ...

Comment: What is your definition of $arg(z)$? does it take values in $S^1$ or in $\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$?  The way I think of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, you need to be able to apply them to functions with values in $\mathbb{C}$.  On the other hand, I think of $arg(z)$ as taking values in $S^1$.  Once this definition problem has been settled, I would sidestep this formula nonsense and compute Cauchy-Riemann on the composition $arg( \operatorname{e}^{s+it} ) = t$ or $=t (mod 2\pi)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Neal points out in the comments, there's no need to use an explicit formula for $\arg$ because there is a more general, and very simple, principle at work here. Any complex-analytic function $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ must be constant, but the argument function is nonconstant. The Cauchy-Riemann equations tell us, because the imaginary part $v:=0$ is constant, that $u_x$ and $u_y$ are also $0$ and hence $u$ (the real part) is constant. This sidesteps any formal or technical work you would otherwise need to do here.

Answer (score 0):

$\arg(z)$ is not an analytic function. As for being analytic, a function must satisfy Cauchy-Riemann Equations which require $u(x,y)$ and $iv(x,y)$. The argument of $z$ yields only a real part therefore Cauchy Riemann equations are not satisfied.

Comment: What's new is your answer?